# Amazon aws sdk AmazonEC2clientBuilder error

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services

i am trying to develop an amazon EC2 Client using java in Eclipse. While reading the official documentation for setting up the region for my client(to launch instances programatically later) it is mentioned to use AmazonEC2ClientBuilder, but I am having difficulty in understanding its usage. Can anybody help me?

Source Code:
AmazonEC2 client=AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(credentials).build();
        client.AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().setRegion("US-WEST2");

The first 2 Lines works Fine but Last one Doesn't. When I try to use set region function of AmazonEC2 ,there is a prompt that it is deprecated.

SDK:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#builder--

Answer (score 0):

Look at this first line of code:

```
client = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(credentials).build();
```

The variable `client` is an `AmazonEC2Client` object (you should have declared it as such higher up in your code). On the second line you are trying to call a method on the `AmazonEC2Client` object. You aren't using the `AmazonEC2ClientBuilder` anymore. You've already built your client object in the first line of code, and now you want to call a method on that object in the next line, like so:

```
client.setRegion("US-WEST2");
```

However that method is deprecated and it is recommended you call the `setRegion` method on the `AmazonEC2ClientBuilder` instead. So you would remove the second line entirely, and change the first line to this:

```
client = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard()
     .withCredentials(credentials)
     .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
     .build();
```